# POST only when the value doesnt exists with GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have POST API which always post the body, but i have to do a GET API prior to POST and do post only when the record doesnt exists in my GET API Response. Any help would be appreciated ?

My sample POST:

```
fetch('posturl', {
method: 'POST',
mode: 'cors',
body: JSON.stringify({ 
Memberno: '10' 
})
})
.then(function (response) {
return response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let getResult = await fetch('geturl', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
        Memberno: '10' 
    })
});
// you should also probably check for statusCode if it's between 200-299
if (getResult.body !== undefined || getResult.body !== null) {
// doPost ...
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. let me try this.